# tabs section in javascript not working in codeigniter framework php

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a tabs section in javascript and HTML, which is working fine on my localhost, now I implemented it on codeigniter framework and uploaded on my server, the live URL is:

[enter link description here][1]

The code is like below:

```js
$(".tabz_content").hide();
$(".tabz_content:first").hide();

//tab mode

$("ul.tabz li").click(function () {

    $(".tabz_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
    $("ul.tabz li").removeClass("activeking");
    $(this).addClass("activeking");

    $(".tabz-accordion_heading").removeClass("d_active");
    $(".tabz-accordion_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");

});


/* acoordion mode */

$(".tabz-accordion_heading").click(function () {

    $(".tabz_content").hide();
    var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#" + d_activeTab).fadeIn();

    $(".tabz-accordion_heading").removeClass("d_active");
    $(this).addClass("d_active");

    $("ul.tabz li").removeClass("activeking");
    $("ul.tabz li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("activeking");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://booktheparty.in/zubi/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="industrys">


  <ul class="tabz">
    <li class="SC" rel="tabz1">
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </p>
      <Br />
      <p class="learnMoreSC">Learn More</p>
    </li>
    <li class="VM" rel="tabz2">
      <h2>Our Vision</h2>
      <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </p><br />
      <p class="learnMoreVM">Learn More</p>
    </li>
    <li class="SW" rel="tabz3">
      <h2>Our Value</h2>
      <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
      <Br />
      <p class="learnMoreSW">Learn More</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tabz_container">
    <div class="tabzSC">
      <h3 class="tabz-accordion_heading" rel="tabz1">Secondary Containment</h3>
      <div id="tabz1" class="tabz_content">
        <div class="tabLeft">
          <img src="http://www.noupe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/01-secrets-unique-product-photography.jpg" width="300px" />
        </div>
        <div class="tabRight">
          <h2 class="industrys">Secondary Containment<br /></h2>
          <p>The </p>
          <br />
          <br /><a class="oPage SC" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=233"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Visit Overview Page</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab2 -->
    <div class="tabzVM">
      <h3 class="tabz-accordion_heading" rel="tabz2">Vaults and Manholes</h3>
      <div id="tabz2" class="tabz_content">
        <div class="tabLeft">
          <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_5rlxf3T9Z9U/TC5PBYV-p-I/AAAAAAAAIYA/BH74SEFthQg/lost+message.jpg" width="300px" />
        </div>
        <div class="tabRight">
          <h2 class="industrys">Vaults and Manholes<br /></h2>
          <p>The</p>
          <br />
          <br /><a class="oPage VM" href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Visit Overview Page</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab3 -->
    <div class="tabzSW">
      <h3 class="tabz-accordion_heading" rel="tabz3">Storm•Water</h3>
      <div id="tabz3" class="tabz_content">
        <div class="tabLeft">
          <img src="https://img0.etsystatic.com/018/1/5863088/il_570xN.492273122_aghw.jpg" width="300px" />
        </div>
        <div class="tabRight">
          <h2 class="industrys">Storm•Water<br /></h2>
          <p>The </p>
          <br />
          <br /><a class="oPage SW" href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Visit Overview Page</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab4 -->
  </div>

</section>
```

This is the complete code for the tabs section, now when I added this to my codignter website, the tabs are not working. I have tried everything like removing other styles, removing the whole page design and simply copy pasting my whole code only in that page, but nothing is working, I think there is a problem with the codeigniter framework which is making the tabs not to work, only in codeigniter the tabs are not working, I also uploaded the code inside a folder in my server and its working [enter link description here][2]

I don't know what the problem with codeigniter is, as I am new to this. Can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here. Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://www.booktheparty.in/aboutus
[2]: http://booktheparty.in/zubi/

Comment: @CBroe, i have seen those errors, its coming from other sections, as I told, I have also removed all the styles and sections and tried keeping this section only, but still its not working in codeigniter

Comment: _“I have also removed all the styles and sections and tried keeping this section only, but still its not working in codeigniter”_ - then give us an example URL that shows _that_ situation at least, so that _we_ don’t have to wade through the rest of _your_ errors.

Comment: `var cart_products='<?php echo json_encode($cart_products); ?>';` This line in your javascript **will not work** and is breaking your javascript. You cannot have PHP code in your js file. This error is being shown in the console, so as CBroe mentioned, you **need** to address the errors in your console.

Comment: @CBroe i have updated the page, removed the rest sections, styles and everything. only kept the tabs section with its styles and js . its not working. please check

Comment: I put your code in a fiddle and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/m5qzrbg3/, kind of

Comment: @Vickel bro the code works fine, but its not working in codeigniter

Comment: Your code returned by the CI version appears to have been “minified”, but in an improper way. In your working example, the comment `//tab mode` is on its own line, in the CI version _all_ of that JS code is smushed together in one single line, `<script> $(".tabz_content").hide(); $(".tabz_content:first").hide(); //tab mode $("ul.tabz li").click(…`, so _everything_ after the `//` is considered a comment.

Comment: structure your CI with 3 views: header, content and footer. Place all header info in the header, load the css files there, content has your tabs code. Footer: load your js files and place your js code.

Comment: @CBroe thank you so much brother, from 2days I am trying to solve it :) . thanks alot